# Fabric JS drag Circle along a Line

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to drag a circle along a line with fabric.js, so when a user selects the circle with the mouse and drags it, it will only move along the line.
Here is a small fiddle of what I've done with 1 line and 1 Circle, which should move along the line:
[MoveTheCircle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz3a1oyt/107/)

The Circle is moving, but with wrong borders. (The moving logic is really confusing, sorry for that :/, i tried to comment it helpfully)

Here is my code, so far (to see it in action, see the fiddle):

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

var line1 = new fabric.Line([50, 50, 100, 70], {
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  left: 80,
  top: 50,
  scaleX: 2,
  scaleY: 2,
  selectable: false
});

var c = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 80,
  top: 50,
  strokeWidth: 2,
  radius: 5,
  fill: '#000',
  stroke: '#000'
});
c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;
c.line1 = line1;

canvas.add(line1, c);


/**
 * Calculates the dot product of two 2-Dimensional Vectors.
 */
function dot_vec(v1_x, v1_y, v2_x, v2_y){
    return (v1_x*v2_x) + (v1_y*v2_y);
}

/**
 * Calculates the magnitude(length) of a 2-Dimensional Vector.
 */
function magnitudeVec(v_x, v_y){
    return Math.sqrt( (v_x*v_x) + (v_y*v_y) );
}


function proj_vec(pBase_x, pBase_y, pEnd_x, pEnd_y, pEnd2_x, pEnd2_y){
    //=== vec from p1 to p2 ===
    var v1_x = (pEnd_x - pBase_x);
    var v1_y = (pEnd_y - pBase_y);

    //=== vec from oldLinePoint to p2 ===
    var v2_x = (pEnd2_x - pBase_x);
    var v2_y = (pEnd2_y - pBase_y);

    //=== proj v1 on v2 ===
    var vProj = proj_vec(v1_x, v1_y, v2_x, v2_y);

    //=== tar vec ===
    var vTar_x = pBase_x + vProj[0];
    var vTar_y = pBase_y + vProj[1];

    return [vTar_x, vTar_y];
}

function proj_vec(v1_x, v1_y, v2_x, v2_y){
    //=== dot product v1 v2 ===
    var v1v2_dot = dot_vec(v1_x, v1_y, v2_x, v2_y);

    //=== magnitude of v2 ===
    var v1_mag = magnitudeVec(v1_x, v1_y);


    //=== vec proj. v1 to v2 ===
    var facVProj = (v1v2_dot) / (v1_mag*v1_mag);
    var vProj_x = facVProj * v1_x;
    var vProj_y = facVProj * v1_y;

    return [vProj_x, vProj_y];
}



canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  var object = e.target;
  var objType = object.get('type');
  object.setCoords();
  var mouse = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

    //=== vec from line start to line end ===
    var vector_linestart_lineend_x = (line1.x1 - line1.x2);
    var vector_linestart_lineend_y = (line1.y1 - line1.y2);

    //=== vec from mouse to line end ===
    var vector_mouse_line_x = (mouse.x - line1.x2);
    var vector_mouse_line_y = (mouse.y - line1.y2);

    //=== vec proj. v1 to v2 ===
    var vProj = proj_vec(vector_linestart_lineend_x, vector_linestart_lineend_y, vector_mouse_line_x, vector_mouse_line_y);
    var vProj_x = vProj[0];
    var vProj_y = vProj[1];

    //=== target result ===
    var vTar_x = line1.x2 + vProj_x;
    var vTar_y = line1.y2 + vProj_y;


    //=== clip Point between endpoints ===
    var vProj_len = magnitudeVec(vProj_x, vProj_y);
    var v1_len = magnitudeVec(vector_linestart_lineend_x, vector_mouse_line_y);

    if (vProj_len < 0) {
        vTar_x = line1.x2;
        vTar_y = line1.y2;
    }
    if (vProj_len > v1_len) {
        vTar_x = line1.x1;
        vTar_y = line1.y1;
    }

    // console.log(vTar_x + " " + vTar_y);

   object.set({'left': vTar_x});
   object.set({'top': vTar_y});

});
```

Thank you for your help!